# Qt c++. How to specify the path to save records?

Tags: c++, qt, qtmultimedia

I have a `QAudioRecorder` object, the audio recording is successful, but the recordings are saved in the default directory, how can I specify my location to store the recordings? Used `QAudioRecorder::setOutputLocation()` unsuccessfully.

Comment: It's a good idea if you provide your target platform as well. It's something very important when it comes to directory structures and related permissions. Please also show how you are using ```::setOutputLocation```

Comment: ***Used QAudioRecorder::setOutputLocation(). unsuccessfully*** I am pretty sure for help you will have to show how you use that and what QUrl you set.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, it was only missing `file:///`

Modify your path like this and it will work:

```
recorder->setOutputLocation(QUrl("file:///C:/mypath/test123.mp3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

the **QAudioRecorder** class inherits the QMediaRecorder, this class has a property for this feature under the name "**outputLocation**" and with the Access functions:

```
QUrl    outputLocation() const
bool    setOutputLocation(const QUrl &location)
```

you can achieve that... here more info: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediarecorder.html#outputLocation-prop

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediarecorder.html) has some good examples on how you can use `setOutPutLocation()`.

```
audioRecorder = new QAudioRecorder;

QAudioEncoderSettings audioSettings;
audioSettings.setQuality(QMultimedia::HighQuality);

audioRecorder->setEncodingSettings(audioSettings);

audioRecorder->setOutputLocation(QUrl::fromLocalFile("file.mp3"));
audioRecorder->record();
```

It can also be used with an absolute path:

```
audioRecorder->setOutputLocation(QUrl("file:///C:/path/file.mp3"));
```

According to [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediarecordercontrol.html#setOutputLocation), `setOutPutLocation()`:

> ***Sets the output location and returns if this operation is successful.***
> If file at the output location already exists, it should be
> overwritten.
>
> The location can be relative or empty; in this case the service should
> use the system specific place and file naming scheme.
>
> After recording has started, the backend should report the actual file
> location with actualLocationChanged() signal.

To make sure that your method-call works you can look at the return value when you call it. Or you can call this method: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediarecordercontrol.html#outputLocation which will:

> Returns the current output location being used.

If `setOutPutLocation()` is successful `outputLocation()` should return the same value.